# Mesos agent registration via http api

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I have a mesos cluster running. I want to register new agent nodes to mesos cluster via HTTP APIs.  Please let me know the url path and post values to send across to the master nodes endpoint.

thanks

Comment: When a Mesos agent is started on a host, it will automatically attempt to register with the master. Having a script hit an endpoint to cause agent registration to occur doesn't really make sense. What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am doing autoscaling of the agent servers based on some metrics in AWS. So based on some metrics if my program launches instances. I want to call register agent to the master instance endpoint.

Comment: If your autoscaling mechanism creates new AWS instances, then you'd want to start `mesos-agent` on the new instance, which will take care of registering with the master.